# How to calculate mean value for Niblack threshold algorithm

Tags: android, algorithm, matlab, opencv, image-processing

I want to implement `Niblack` threshold algorithm with usage of `OpenCV4Android` lib. I tried to get look at some codes online (mainly `MatLab` and `C++` ones) but I have problem with fully understanding it. Because of that I want simply to stick to the threshold formula and create threshold method on my own:

```
 if pixel > (mean + k * standard_deviation) 
     pixel = object; 
 else 
     pixel = background; 
 end
```

k - value of this parameter is usually -0.2 by default 
standard_deviation - easy to get if we have mean: ((mean calculated from image^2) - mean^2)^0.5

And there is my problem. How to actually calculate mean here? Is it a constant value, calculated from whole image, for each thhresholded pixel that I could get by:

```
Core.mean(Mat src);
```

Or maybe it's a mean value of N x N neighborhood around pixel? There is also constructor:

```
Core.mean(Mat src, mask);
```

But acording to documentation: http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/core/Core.html#mean(org.opencv.core.Mat,org.opencv.core.Mat)
It doesn't look like something I need...

So let's say I'm doing iteration through whole matrix representing image I want to binarize. Each pixel is getting through logic:

```
if pixel > (mean + k * standard_deviation)
```

Can someone understanding this Algorithm tell me how should mean value be calculated? Different for each pixel or same for all of them?